# Ignore nested structures in numpy's array creation

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to write to a vlen hdf5 dataset, for that I am using `h5py.Dataset.write_direct` to speed up the process. Suppose I have a list of numpy arrays (e.g. given by `cv2.findContours`), and by dataset:

```
dataset = h5file.create_dataset('dataset', \
                                shape=..., \
                                dtype=h5py.special_type(vlen='int32'))
contours = [numpy array, ...]
```

For writing `contours` to a destination given by the slice `dest`, I must first convert `contours` to a numpy array of numpy arrays:

```
contours = numpy.array(contours) # shape=(len(contours),); dtype=object
dataset.write_direct(contours, None, dest)
```

But this only works, if all numpy arrays in contours have different shapes, e.g.:

```
contours = [np.zeros((10,), 'int32'), np.zeros((10,), 'int32')]
contours = numpy.array(contours) # shape=(2,10); dtype='int32'
```

The question is: How can I tell numpy to create an array of objects?

---

Possible solutions:

Manual creation:

```
contours_np = np.empty((len(contours),), dtype=object)
for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    contours_np[i] = contour
```

But loops are super slow, thus using `map`:

```
map(lambda (i, contour): contour.__setitem_(i, contour),  \
    enumerate(contours))
```

I have tested a second option, which is twice as fast as the above, but also super ugly:

```
contours = np.array(contours + [None])[:-1]
```

Here are the micro benchmarks:

```
l = [np.random.normal(size=100) for _ in range(1000)]
```

Option 1:

```
$ start = time.time(); l_array = np.zeros(shape=(len(l),), dtype='O'); map(lambda (i, c): l_array.__setitem__(i, c), enumerate(l)); end = time.time(); print("%fms" % ((end - start) * 10**3))
0.950098ms
```

Option 2:

```
$ start = time.time(); np.array(l + [None])[:-1]; end = time.time(); print("%fms" % ((end - start) * 10**3))
0.409842ms
```

This looks kind of ugly, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this version

```
contours_np = np.empty((len(contours),), dtype=object)
for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    contours_np[i] = contour
```

you can replace the loop with the single statement

```
contours_np[...] = contours
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution appears to be to create the "outer" array first (with an 'object' dtype), then fill the elements with the inner array.

Thus:

```
contours = [np.zeros((10,), 'int32'), np.zeros((10,), 'int32')]
a = np.empty(len(contours), dtype=np.object)
for i in range(len(contours)):
    a[i] = contours[i]
print(a)
print()
print(repr(a))
```

results in

```
[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)]

array([array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)], dtype=object)
```